# How can I generate interactive plots with PlotylyJS and Julia in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, plotly.js

To generate a static plot, say of 10 random data points, in Jupyter notebooks using Julia I write the following.

```
using Pkg;
Pkg.add("Plots")
Pkg.add("PyPlot")
using Plots
pyplot()

plot(rand(10))
gui()
```

As expected, this results in a graph of 10 random data points.
[image: graph of 10 random data points]

On the contrary, if I try plotting an equivalent graph using PlotlyJS (or Plotly/GR) by writing the below code, no output is. No errors are thrown, but no graph is shown either.

```
using Pkg;
Pkg.add("Plots")
Pkg.add("PlotlyJS")
using Plots
plotlyjs()

plot(rand(10))
gui()
```

I have seen others use PlotlyJS to generate interactive plots inside a Jupyter notebook. I can already generate interactive plots with PlotlyJS as well as GR when I run my Julia using the Julia extension for VSCode, but I would prefer to be able to generate interactive plots inside of my Jupyter notebook. What software do I need to install and what settings do I need to configure to be able to create interactive plots with PlotlyJS inside of a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: There is unfortunately [an issue](https://github.com/sglyon/PlotlyJS.jl/issues/278) with `PlotlyJS` and `Plotly` related to `WebIO` that prevents plots appearing in Jupyter notebooks. You may workaround the issue by downgrading `WebIO` to version `0.7.0`. To do so please execute the Pkg command `]add WebIO@0.7.0`. You may want to pin this package at this version for now so that it is not updated. I think you should also omit the call to `gui`. You can write `display(plot(rand(10))` or just let the plotting expression be the last one in the cell to display the plot.

Comment: @hckr Thanks. Your proposed work around works perfectly.